# Apex Mock Domain Factory Error

Tags: apex, fflib, apexmock

Running into an issue with Implementing Apex Mocking. Everything works fine until I try to set the domain mock in the domain class. Here is My Code:

```
@IsTest
    private static void testMocking(){
        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
        fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork unitOfWorkMock = new fflib_SObjectMocks.SObjectUnitOfWork(mocks);


        //MOCK
        IOpportunities opportunitiesMock = (IOpportunities) mocks.mock(Opportunities.class);
        OpportunitiesSelector opportunitiesSelectorMock = (OpportunitiesSelector) mocks.mock(OpportunitiesSelector.class);


        //STUBBING HERE

        //SET MOCKS
        Application.selector.setMock(opportunitiesSelectorMock);
        Application.domain.setMock( opportunitiesMock );
        Application.UOW.setMock(unitOfWorkMock);
```

When trying to save this I get :

```
"Error:(143, 28) Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setMock(IOpportunities) from the type fflib_Application.DomainFactory"
```

No Idea why, Every example looks to me like I have this correct.

Comment: Did you actually implement `fflib_ISObjectDomain`? You crucially have not shown us how you defined `IOpportunities`.

Answer (score 2):

The signature for `Application.Domain.setMock` is:

```
void setMock(fflib_ISObjectDomain mockDomain)
```

Your mock domain was defined as:

```
IOpportunities opportunitiesMock = (IOpportunities) mocks.mock(Opportunities.class);
```

Your class `Opportunities` implements `IOpportunities` but most likely, you defined `IOpportunities` as:

```
public interface IOpportunities {
  ...
}
```

`IOpportunities` is not an instance of type `fflib_ISObjectDomain`.

As you discovered, you  want the mock domain to be cast to the type supported by setMock:

```
Application.Domain.setMock( (fflib_ISObjectDomain) opportunitiesMock );
```

Alternatively, you could follow the example in Salesforce Lightning Platform Enterprise Architecture 3rd edition page 506

```
Contestants mockDomain = (Contestants) mocks.mock(Contestants.class);
... 
Application.Domain.setMock(mockDomain);
```

since `Contestants` extends `fflib_SObjectDomain` which implements `fflib_ISobjectDomain`

*replace `Contestants` with `Opportunities`*

Answer (score 1):

I found something that says it should be:

```
        Application.domain.setMock( (fflib_ISObjectDomain) opportunitiesMock );
```

Comment: worked for me!!